# SwiftUI MacOS QuickLook preview of files

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swiftui

I am trying to display a preview of files (like PDF, Pages, Microsoft Docs) in my SwiftUI application for MacOS.

I found Apple's [QuickLook](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quicklook) framework, which looks perfect for that use. Can I use it in SwiftUI? If I look up the documentation at Apple, I find the `QLPreviewController` which is a UIViewController.

My approach would, to wrap that UIViewController into a SwiftUI view.. is that the best way? Has anyone tried to do that already?

Summary: how can I display file previews in my SwiftUI MacOS app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured it out finally.

I was able to use the `QLPreviewView`, which generates a preview view for me. I wrapped it inside a `NSViewRepresentable` and it worked :)

Comment: Can you provide the code for your solution? @davidev

Comment: @Heyman https://stackoverflow.com/a/70369611/4423545

Comment: @Andrew it doesn't work on Mac Catalyst. I get the error: `Cannot find type 'NSViewRepresentable' in scope`

Comment: @Heyman `import SwiftUI
import AppKit
import Quartz` . And dont forget to upwote answers that helped you :)

Comment: @Andrew i am not able to use Quartz. I get this error on import: `Could not build Objective-C module 'Quartz'`

Comment: hm... you're right, quartz is absent for catalyst -- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartz

Comment: @Andrew I even tried using quickLookPreview view modifier but i get error on the catalyst for an old project. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70341461/how-to-use-quicklookpreview-modifier-in-swiftui?noredirect=1#comment124345424_70341461 I don't know what option is left now

Comment: @Heyman try something similar to https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/658258 looks like preview works in different base on Catalyst/IOS and macos versions. Also maybe this will be useful https://www.raywenderlich.com/19636179-custom-thumbnails-and-previews-with-quick-look-on-ios

Comment: @Heyman try this https://iosexample.com/quicklook-preview-for-swiftui-on-mac-catalyst/

Answer (score 1):

This may be what you are looking for

### https://danielsaidi.com/blog/2022/06/27/using-quicklook-with-swiftui

```swift
import SwiftUI
import QuickLook

struct ContentView: View {

    @State
    var url: URL?

    var body: some View {
        Button("Preview") {
            url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "meadow", withExtension: "jpg")
        }.quickLookPreview($url)
    }
}
```