# How to use .quickLookPreview modifier in swiftui

Tags: macos, swiftui, mac-catalyst, quicklook, viewmodifier

I am trying to use the view modifier `.quickLookPreview` introduced in iOS 14, macOS 11 macCatalyst 14 but I get this error `Value of type 'some View' has no member 'quickLookPreview'` every time I try to use the modifier on a macOS or mac catalyst target. On iOS, this works fine.
What is the right way to present this modifier on a mac?

```
import SwiftUI
import QuickLook


struct ContentView: View {

@State var documentUrl: URL?

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {

    ZStack {
        
        Button("Press Me", action: {
            documentUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: "somelocalfileURLPath")
        })
        
        
       
    }
    .navigationTitle("Open File")
    .quickLookPreview($documentUrl)
        
    }
    
}

}
```

**xcode 13.1** **MacOS 12.1**

Comment: Can you share your code with us?

Comment: @xTwisteDx Updated the question with code

Comment: This needs a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Yrb what else is missing? This is the most basic version of the code that runs well on iOS but throws the error on mac.

Comment: How are you obtaining your URL path? Is it an app file? What kind of file is it?

Comment: @Yrb the URL doesn't really matter in this case. It is just a dummy URL and it still opens as a blank document. I also tested it on a real URL of a local file

Comment: The code runs fine then on Xcode 13.2, macOS 11.6.2. Did you make a new app and test the code you posted, before posting?

Comment: @Yrb Okay, I will update to Xcode 13.2 and run it again. Thanks

Comment: And make a new test app.

Comment: @Yrb why does it still throw error on an old project even though it runs on Xcode version 13.2?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240118/discussion-between-yrb-and-heyman).

Comment: Heyman and Yrb,  did you manage to solve the problem?  If so, could you post the code for getting .quickLookPreview() to work in both iOS and MacOS.

Comment: @KeithB No, I never got it to work. I have been asked by an apple developer to file a bug but I don't have the time to do that.

Comment: Heyman,  please checkout my question and answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71487449/in-my-mac-app-how-can-i-open-a-local-pdf-file-using-a-swiftui-button .  It worked on my Mac for me.

Comment: @KeithB Yeah run the same code now in Xcode 13.2 and I see the issue is fixed and it works.

Comment: I deleted my previous comment. Sorry, I was wrong, I missed to copy the `QuickLook` import. Now it works. For reference, the deleted comment: "It doesn't work for me on Xcode 13.3, I tried the code example above, and get the same Value of type 'some View' has no member 'quickLookPreview'. I tried it both in a MacOS and an iOS project, with several of the latest versions as deployment targets."

Comment: It appears support for this has been completely removed for Catalyst? No mention of Catalyst at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/quicklookpreview(_:) and I'm unable to build for Catalyst with the .quickLookPreview modifier.

Comment: @LeoKlaus no it is not supported on catalyst

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is gone now in Xcode 13.2

So the right way to use the modifier is valid, it was just probably some bug in earlier xcode versions.

Comment: I deleted my previous comment. Sorry, I was wrong, I missed to copy the QuickLook import. Now it works. For reference, the deleted comment: "It doesn't work for me on Xcode 13.3, I tried the code example above, and get the same Value of type 'some View' has no member 'quickLookPreview'. I tried it both in a MacOS and an iOS project, with several of the latest versions as deployment targets."