# SwiftUI display gif image

Tags: swift, macos, image, swiftui, animated-gif

The way to display animated gif image in swiftUI

because of Image

```
Image("fall-leaves")
```

does not support gifs

answer below

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Easiest and fastest way to display gif image in swiftUI - is to use `Preview` / `QuickLook (QL)` / `QLPreviewView`

Quartz available only in macOS 10.4+ https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartz

```
import SwiftUI
import Quartz

struct QLImage: NSViewRepresentable {
    var url: URL
    
    func makeNSView(context: NSViewRepresentableContext<QLImage>) -> QLPreviewView {
        let preview = QLPreviewView(frame: .zero, style: .normal)
        preview?.autostarts = true
        preview?.previewItem = url as QLPreviewItem
        
        return preview ?? QLPreviewView()
    }
    
    func updateNSView(_ nsView: QLPreviewView, context: NSViewRepresentableContext<QLImage>) {
        nsView.previewItem = url as QLPreviewItem
    }
    
    typealias NSViewType = QLPreviewView
}
```

Comment: where and why you would need or use a gif in your app?

Comment: @swiftPunk hah) At the moment I'm working on another one app - image viewer :) But also I will use this thing in taoGit - for previewing of commited images. So this code can be useful in both of projects

Comment: The only use case that I could understand it would be using it as avatar image in chat app or something, but that is not necessary even. Extra unnecessary feature.

Comment: @swiftPunk This is unnecessary feature for developers. But not for UI designers or graphic artists :) You look on the git like a developer. But git can be useful for other professions also. If git-client  will be easy enough to use ofc

Comment: About the use case I have to add that gif is important for sending as message as well, I almost forgot that one. :)

Answer (score 6):

I was having a hard time using this in my macOS app because I try to load my gif file from the local assets rather than a URL.  After looking around for answers, the best answer seems to be putting the gif file into the project folder rather than into the Assets.xcassets and then load the resource into the URL. Somehow Bundle.main.url(forResource: myFile, withExtension: "gif") will return nil if the file isn't in the main project folder.  I checked the ProjectName -> Target -> Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources and the gif file is there automatically when I add to the project.  The weird thing is somehow the gif file is not available if it's in the Assets.xcassets.

I updated the QLImage struct from @Andrew to load the gif file by name (make sure to add the gif directly to your project as mentioned above).  Here's the updated code below.  You need to also provide a sample gif image called preview-gif or call it whatever you want and match the name in the preview section.

```
import SwiftUI
import Quartz

struct QLImage: NSViewRepresentable {
    
    private let name: String

    init(_ name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
    
    func makeNSView(context: NSViewRepresentableContext<QLImage>) -> QLPreviewView {
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: name, withExtension: "gif")
        else {
            let _ = print("Cannot get image \(name)")
            return QLPreviewView()
        }
        
        let preview = QLPreviewView(frame: .zero, style: .normal)
        preview?.autostarts = true
        preview?.previewItem = url as QLPreviewItem
        
        return preview ?? QLPreviewView()
    }
    
    func updateNSView(_ nsView: QLPreviewView, context: NSViewRepresentableContext<QLImage>) {
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: name, withExtension: "gif")
        else {
            let _ = print("Cannot get image \(name)")
            return
        }
        nsView.previewItem = url as QLPreviewItem
    }
    
    typealias NSViewType = QLPreviewView
}

struct QLImage_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        QLImage("preview-gif")
    }
}
```

This will return a view, but you need to specify the frame size or you can't see anything.  Use it like this it a view:

```
 QLImage("myGif").frame(width: 500, height: 300, alignment: .center)
```

Set whatever frame size is appropriate.  All the other view-related properties are also available with this.

Hope this helps somebody else who is trying to display GIF images from local resources on macOS.  Apple should really make it easier to display animated GIF since it's being used everywhere these days.

Answer (score 1):

### iOS solution (if someone needed)

(Not usable for macOS)

It defines a GifImageView struct that conforms to UIViewRepresentable, allowing us to use a WKWebView to display a GIF.

The GifImageView takes a GIF image name as a parameter.
Inside makeUIView, it creates a WKWebView, loads the GIF data, and displays it.

The updateUIView function ensures the view reloads when needed.
To use this GifImageView, simply create an instance in your SwiftUI view hierarchy, as shown in the ContentView.

Feel free to adjust the frame size (width and height) as needed to fit your UI

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

enum URLType {
  case name(String) // local file name of gif
  case url(URL) // remote url

  var url: URL? {
    switch self {
      case .name(let name):
        return Bundle.main.url(forResource: name, withExtension: "gif")
      case .url(let remoteURL):
        return remoteURL
    }
  }
}

struct GifImageView: UIViewRepresentable {
    private let name: String
    init(_ name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let webview = WKWebView()
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: name, withExtension: "gif")!
        let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
        
        webview.load(data,mimeType: "image/gif",characterEncodingName: "UTF-8", baseURL: url.deletingLastPathComponent())
        return webview
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        uiView.reload()
    }
}
```

Comment: there is tag "macOS" in the question. So UI classes are inaccessible :)

Comment: Thanks @Andrew_STOP_RU_WAR_IN_UA
I was also looking for answers but it might help some one